# How to decode a JWT using C# JWT Package with Signing Certificate

Tags: c#, oauth, jwt, adfs3.0

I am calling ADFS for getting an access token using OAuth Authorization Code Grant.
I am getting an access token back in the form

```
{"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dC...."
 "token_type":"bearer",
 "expires":3600}
```

Now, i am copying the access_token value and pasting it in https://jwt.io
It decodes perfectly but with an Invalid Signature.

The Header for Jwt.io returns:

```
{
"typ": "JWT",
"alg": "RS256",
"x5t": "eQKi04zWoOV3eLmNNBrI2_rbqSY"
}
```

I have the pem token signing certificate that looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG0zCCBbugAwIBAgIKUJvNQgAAAAANxTA...
BgNVBAcTBEtlbnQxJjAkBgNVBAoTHVR...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now, how to verify the token with the Certificate using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt or with any other method.

Kindly, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research, i found the answer. Posting it here so it will be helpful to others.

```
  string token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1.."
  var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
//Read Token for Getting the User Details
  var parsedJwt = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken; 

//Create A Certificate Object that will read the .CER/.PEM/.CRT file as String
 X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CertficationString));

 var certToken = new X509SecurityToken(clientCertificate);

 var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {   
        IssuerSigningToken = certToken,
        ValidAudience = audience,
        ValidIssuer = issuer,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };


    try
    {
       SecurityToken validatedToken;
       var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n {1}", err.Message, err.StackTrace);
    }
```